# SparkStreaming WordCount error / grammar

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, word-count

I'm referring https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java and trying to build Spark wordcount example but some code is not compiling in Eclipse and showing the error below.

The code that is throwing the error is:

---

```
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public Iterator<String> call(String x) {
        return Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator();
      }
    });
```

---

Compilation Error:

> The return type is incompatible with
>   FlatMapFunction.call(String)

Here's details: Spark 1.6.1, Java 1.7_67, Eclipse Kepler,CDH5.7
I have tried Changing JDK version and adding all Hadoop Jars as external Jar, Maven dependencies but this error still exist.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [JavaDoc of FlatmapFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html), you should be returning a `java.lang.Iterable<String>`, and you are returning a `java.util.Iterator<String>`.
Since Iterator does not implement the Iterable interface, the code will not be compatible. Luckily, the `List` interface does extend the `Iterable` interface, so all you have to do is:

- Remove the `.iterator()` call from the end of your created list
- Fix the return type of the `call(String x)` method to be `Iterable<String>`

This change probably from Iterator to Iterable probably happened in a recent version of Spark, and the example did not get updated yet.

Comment: it is much simpler this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38881118/5581893

Comment: It is simpler because it makes use of Java 8 lambdas. But OP said he is using Java 1.7, which does not support them.