# Spark 2.0.0 Arrays.asList not working - incompatible types

Tags: java, apache-spark

Following code works with Spark 1.5.2 but not with Spark 2.0.0. I am using Java 1.8.

```
final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
sparkConf.setMaster("local[4]"); // Four threads
final JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
final JavaRDD<String> javaRDDLines = javaSparkContext.textFile("4300.txt");
final JavaRDD<String> javaRDDWords = javaRDDLines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
```

I get following error

```
Error:(46, 66) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to java.util.Iterator<U>
```

I am unable to figure out if the Spark API has changed or something else. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It is wrong even in the current version of the quickstart guide of spark! 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In 2.0, [`FlatMapFunction.call()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html#call(T)) returns an `Iterator` rather than `Iterable`. Try this:

```
JavaRDD<String> javaRDDWords = javaRDDLines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator())
```