# Cannot resolve method 'flatMap(<lambdaexpression>)' error

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am new to apache spark and trying to run the [wordcount example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java) . But intellij editor gives me the error at line 47 ***Cannot resolve method 'flatMap()'  error***.

Edit :
This is the line where I am getting the error

```
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s)).iterator());
```

Comment: What version of the JDK is your project using? What language level?

Comment: jdk version 1.8

Comment: Ignoring IntelliJ's message, what is the message you get from the compiler when you try to build?

Comment: Error:(47, 38) java: cannot access scala.ScalaObject
  class file for scala.ScalaObject not found

Comment: Do you have all necessary libraries in you classpath/dependencies?

Comment: yes I do . Flatmap is a method of JavaRDD and I have imported it . I think the problem is that it is not accepting lambda expression as input . Any idea on overcoming that?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an older version of Spark that expects `Iterable` rather than `Iterator` from the `flatMap()` function. Try this:

```
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s)));
```

See also [Spark 2.0.0 Arrays.asList not working - incompatible types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880956/spark-2-0-0-arrays-aslist-not-working-incompatible-types)

Answer (score 0):

Stream#flatMap is used for combining multiple streams into one, so the supplier method you provided must return a Stream result.

you can try like this:

`lines.stream().flatMap(line -> Stream.of(SPACE.split(line)))
                .map(word -> // map to JavaRDD)`

Answer (score -1):

`flatMap` method take a `FlatMapFunction`as parameter which is not annotated with @FunctionalInterface. So indeed you can not use it as a lambda.

Just build a real `FlatMapFunction`object as parameter and you will be sure of it.

Comment: Functional interfaces don't need to be annotated.

Answer (score -1):

`flatMap()` is Java 8 Stream API. I think you should check the IDEA compile java version.

compile java version
[image: [1]]